# Do questions about food additives belong on Lifehacks or elsewhere?

Tags: support

Specifically I'd like to know what a certain line on a foreign (USA) product means. It says something about the product's additives and I'd like to know what it means and what is actually in the product.

Where should I ask this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not on-topic at Lifehacks as there is no hackery involved to solve a problem.

Your best bet is probably [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), which covers cooking.
Check their [tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) first to make sure that what you wish to ask is on-topic there.